# How to find the common supernet between two networks?

Tags: subnet

Imagine I have two networks:

```
192.168.20.0
192.168.21.0
```

How can I find the common supernet to give to a router so any external router can access these two network by using only the supernet address?

Comment: Please, Please, Please! Read this question and the first answer (top to bottom) before asking any more IP questions: http://serverfault.com/questions/49765

Comment: Strictly speaking you have not given two networks, you have given two IPv4 addresses.  Your question should have been;  Given IP addresses 192.168.20.0 and 192.168.21.0, what is the minimum network possible that will include both.  The answer is 192.168.20.0 /23.

Comment: A more difficult problem would have been; Given IP addresses 192.168.21.0 and 192.168.22.0, what is the minimum network possible that will include both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert to binary:

```
1100 0000.1010 1000.0001 0100.0000 0000
1100 0000.1010 1000.0001 0101.0000 0000
```

look at how many bits they have in common:

```
XXXX XXXX.XXXX XXXX.XXXX XXX0.000000000
```

Count them up for CIDR notation; or convert to decimal for the subnet mask:

```
CIDR:192.168.20.0/23
Mask:255.255.254.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#ipcalc 192.168.20.0 - 192.168.21.255
deaggregate 192.168.20.0 - 192.168.21.255
192.168.20.0/23
```

Answer (score 0):

Work in binary, you will see the subnet which contains these two networks.
Or use a mask calculator like mine http://dominique.fournier38.fr/?prog=CalculMasque&line=1 in french sorry)